# Suit CRM check box displayed as drop down

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

In Edit view check box filed displays as check box.
[image: Check Box]

But in advanced search, check box displayed as drop down.

[image]

in popup defs field type is bool. how to display this as a check-box in advanced search ?

Answer (score 1):

That is the default of Suite/Sugar CE CRM which display checkbox as a drop-down in advance search. It is defined by field type and you will need to override that field in an upgrade-safe manner(by copying in the custom folder while keeping their current folder hierarchy).

Check complete code inside this file: `include/SugarFields/Fields/Bool/SearchView.tpl` and do changes as you want. you will see tpl files for other views as well.

Answer (score 1):

1.-You need to create a file: `custom/include/SugarFields/Fields/Bool/SearchView.tpl`

2.-Copy this code:

```
{if strval({{sugarvar key='value' stringFormat='false'}}) == "1" || strval({{sugarvar key='value' stringFormat='false'}}) == "yes" || strval({{sugarvar key='value' stringFormat='false'}}) == "on"} 
{assign var="checked" value='checked="checked"'}
{else}
{assign var="checked" value=""}
{/if}
<input type="hidden" name="{{if empty($displayParams.idName)}}{{sugarvar key='name'}}{{else}}{{$displayParams.idName}}{{/if}}" value="0"> 
<input type="checkbox" id="{{if empty($displayParams.idName)}}{{sugarvar key='name'}}{{else}}{{$displayParams.idName}}{{/if}}" 
name="{{if empty($displayParams.idName)}}{{sugarvar key='name'}}{{else}}{{$displayParams.idName}}{{/if}}" 
value="1" title='{{$vardef.help}}' tabindex="{{$tabindex}}" {{if !empty($displayParams.accesskey)}} accesskey='{{$displayParams.accesskey}}' {{/if}}
{$checked} {{$displayParams.field}}>
```

3.-Do a Repair/Rebuild.

Comment: The source of the solution was taken from the @Star anwser: That is the default of Suite/Sugar CE CRM which display checkbox as a drop-down in advance search. It is defined by field type and you will need to override that field in an upgrade-safe manner(by copying in the custom folder while keeping their current folder hierarchy).

Check complete code inside this file: include/SugarFields/Fields/Bool/SearchView.tpl and do changes as you want. you will see tpl files for other views as well.